# Why are all my strings printed as string literals?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, bash, subprocess, python-2.x

I am making a script for a lab that will take an inventory of all servers there along with their stats. I use `subprocess` to pass the output of bash commands into variables in my python code. However, the output I get back frustrates me. On one computer, the output of the following:

```
def codename():
"""
Determines the product name of the actual motherboard/machine that it is used on
:return: Returns the system's codename
"""
sysman = str(subprocess.check_output(('dmidecode', '-s', 'system-manufacturer'))).rstrip() + " "
sysprodname = str(subprocess.check_output(('dmidecode', '-s', 'system-product-name'))).rstrip() + " "
sysver = str(subprocess.check_output(('dmidecode', '-s', 'system-version'))).rstrip()

# Checks for incomplete information

sysinfo = [sysman, sysprodname, sysver]

for i in range(len(sysinfo)):
    if not any(c.isalpha for c in sysinfo[i]):
        sysinfo[i] = ""

sysname = sysman + sysprodname + sysver

if sysname is not None:
    return str(sysname)
else:
    return "---"
```

when called simply by calling `codename()` in Python 2 (2.7 to be precise) will return:

`innotek GmbH VirtualBox 1.2`

while running it in Python 3 (3.6.5) returns:

`b'innotek' GmbH\n' b'VirtualBox\n' b'1.2\n'`.

I am starting to think this is a python specific problem, but on another machine where I write the code (openSUSE Tumbleweed), `python --version` returns:

`Python 3.6.5` 
and `python3 --version` also returns:

`Python 3.6.5`.

However when I run it with `python script.py` I get the well formatted string whereas when I run it with `python3 script.py`, I get the string literal version. Can someone help me make some sense of this?

Comment: That's the output I would suspect if you just run `codename()` instead of `print(codename())` from the interactive interpreter.

Comment: That's a good comment, but I actually do write `print(codename())` in my code, I'll be sure to edit that